# How to change year in date picker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using UIdate picker from https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

> My code is ok

but user who are using this UI date picker can't change current year to next year.

In calendar it will display current date, if someone want's to go in previous year there is no any option.

In documentation ctrl+pageup key will work, it is not working for me.

I am using same code give in date picker(https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

**Thanks In advance**

Comment: Please use comment section if you have any query. If you want to show your code then paste your code by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `changeYear` property on JQuery `datepicker` that you can set to true.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ changeYear: true });
```

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

This will render a select list from which you can choose the year you'd like.

Comment: `$( function() { 
    $('#reportDate').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
});
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ changeYear: true });
  } );`

Answer (score 2):

@Ataur Rahman

I need to use my code like this

`$( function() {
    $('#reportDate').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
      changeYear: true,
      changeMonth: true
});`

Answer (score -1):

You should set `changeYear:true` in jQuery `datepicker` method like this.
Don't forgot to include jquery.js,datepicker.js and datepicker.css  before the code snippet. see the example below.

```js
    $(function() {
        $('#reportDate').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
          changeYear: true
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="text" id="reportDate" value=""/>
```